# Use declared "AS" variable in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query, which doesn't work:

```
$sql = "SELECT dma, COUNT(*) as dma_count, round(dma_count/32434 * 100) as dma_percent FROM {$table} where dma != '0' GROUP BY dma ORDER BY dma_count DESC;";
```

The reason (I know) it doesn't work is because I'm using `dma_count` in this part `round(dma_count/32434 * 100)`.

What's the correct way to do this?

EDIT:

Additional challenge. Instead of using 32434, I want to use a variable. I get the variable like this:

```
$get_total = "SELECT count(DISTINCT `exuid`) from {$table};";
$total = $dbh->query($get_total)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

so my query becomes (with the fix recommended in the comments)

```
$sql = "SELECT dma, COUNT(*) as dma_count, round(COUNT(*)/{$total} * 100) as dma_percent FROM {$table} where dma != '0' GROUP BY dma ORDER BY dma_count DESC;";
```

This doesn't work because I think `$total` is in the wrong format. How can I fix this?

EDIT AGAIN:

Got it! `$total` is just the count of my rows, so I have this instead.

```
SELECT dma, COUNT(*) as dma_count, round(COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$table}) * 100,2) as dma_percent FROM {$table} where dma != '0' GROUP BY dma ORDER BY dma_count DESC;"
```

Comment: use `COUNT(*)` instead of the alias in the equation

Comment: Correct . . . You have learned the SQL standard that column aliases cannot be used in the same select that defines them.

Comment: The select column list isn't actually aliased until after the query has run. It is available to the order by list (which is processed after the rest of the query has run) and in the returned result as the key/column names.

Comment: @Dagon Thanks...this fixed the issue, but I oversimplifed my question and I thought it wouldn't be an issue. Can you look at my edit and see how I can put the pieces together. The `$total` variable is supposed to be just a count of rows in my table, so maybe there's a shortcut for that.

Comment: @Dagon Nevermind...I got it figured out. Thanks. Please post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: a subquery should solve that .. ok you have ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use COUNT(*) in the equation instead of the alias, or the finial answer a sub query. In general avoid sub queries if you can use a join.